# Database.Delete Error

Tags: apex

```
List<Contact> c = [SELECT ID FROM Contact WHERE AccountId !='00190000016ozwL']; 

System.debug(c.size()); 

Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.delete(c, false);
```

This is anonymous apex that I am trying to execute.

I am getting the following error while executing.

```
Illegal assignment from LIST&lt;Database.DeleteResult&gt; to LIST&lt;Database.SaveResult&gt;
```

Not sure why am I getting this error because "c" is a collection only.

Can someone let me know ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Database.delete` returns `Database.deleteResult`. `Database.saveResult` is returned for **insert** and **update** operations.

So you should change you code to:

```
Database.deleteResult[] srList = Database.delete(c, false);
```

You can find more info here: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database_deleteresult.htm

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can do deletes with the SaveResult class

> The result of an insert or update DML operation returned by a Database
>   method.

You should be using the [DeleteResult](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database_deleteresult.htm) classs

> Represents the result of a delete DML operation returned by the
>   Database.delete method.